# Readonly Django ModelAdmin form field with id attribute

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

When you make a form field in a ModelAdmin form read only, Django doesn't give it an id attribute. I have a select field which is editable in the ADD form but read only in the UPDATE form. Is there a way to have Django add the id attribute so that I can target it with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

You can override get_readonly_fields() method to manage read_only field in add and change page separately.
Suppose you want to make readonly field1 and field2 in change page then

```
    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj:
            return ['field1', 'field2']
        else:
            return []
```